# Visualize data from TitanDB

Tags: graph, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, gephi

Today, when I want to visualize the data I hold on Titan DB server I use **Gremlin** to export the data:

```
gremlin>g = TitanFactory.open('../conf/my-titan-db-server.local')
gremlin>g.saveGraphML('../graphExported.graphml')
```

After that, I use **Gephi** to show the exported graph.

**My question:**
Is there a better (shorter) way to visualize the data directly? maybe a Gephi plug-in?

Comment: Nothing that I know of...

Comment: There is a plugin available (if using titan >= 0.9), you can read about it here: http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gephi-plugin Given your example (loading your graph directly in the console rather than using `:remote`) it should work. But I will post a full answer (on how to use with remote) once I double check there aren't easier options.